# SOAP Request call compiled with Eclipse runs fine, compiled with Android Studio, bombs

Tags: android, soap, android-studio

I have an application that is running on a Nexus 7 2012 WIFI using Android 4.4.4 as the OS.  We've compiled the app with Eclipse and it has run with no problems. The app sends requests to a .Net Web Service using SOAP.   We are calling a stored procedure on SQL server that basically gets a date from the server.

However, when running the same application compiled with Android Studio, the web service responds with `Object Reference not set to an instance of an object` error. The code is identical other than the build using gradle.

Here is the SOAP call:

```
    /**
 * Calls the stored proc on the server to return a dataset/SoapObject. This will always run the ProcReader method on the web server.
 * 
 * @param storedProc The Stored Proc to call
 * @param params The parameter(s) for the stored proc (pipe seperated for multiple parameters)
 * @return The SoapObject returned by the Stored Proc call
 * @throws Exception
 */
private static SoapObject callProcServiceForObject(String serviceMethod, String storedProc, String params) throws Exception {
    String NAMESPACE = "http://" + GlobalVars.serviceIP + "/";
    String METHOD_NAME = getMethodName(serviceMethod);
    String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
    String URL = "http://" + GlobalVars.serviceIP + "/ATService.asmx";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    if (GlobalVars.encryptedService) {
        request.addProperty("ePassword", CryptUtil.encryptString(GlobalVars.deviceSerialNumber));
        request.addProperty("eData", CryptUtil.encryptString(GlobalVars.serverDB));
        request.addProperty("eSP_Name", CryptUtil.encryptString(storedProc));
        request.addProperty("eParam", CryptUtil.encryptString(params));
    } else {
        request.addProperty("sPassword", GlobalVars.deviceSerialNumber);
        request.addProperty("sData", GlobalVars.serverDB);
        request.addProperty("sSP_Name", storedProc);
        request.addProperty("sParam", params);
    }
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    // Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, timeout);
    //count up the network traffic
    numberOfBytesTransmitted = numberOfBytesTransmitted + StringToBytes(request.toString());

    SoapObject returnable = null;
    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        returnable = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Msg:" + e.getMessage() + "; SP:" + storedProc + "; Params: " + params + "; Method:" + METHOD_NAME);
    }
    numberOfBytesTransmitted = numberOfBytesTransmitted + StringToBytes(returnable.toString());
    return returnable;
}
```

Anything jump out at anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I didn't have the web config file set up on my .Net service, it had nothing to do at all with Android Studio.